# GDAL installation error "error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to install GDAL with python.But it failed with error.

The command I use is `pip install GDAL`.

```
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include -c extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extensions/gdal_wrap.o -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/gdal
  extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3177:27: fatal error: cpl_vsi_error.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

and

```
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for GDAL
  Running setup.py clean for GDAL
Failed to build GDAL
Installing collected packages: GDAL
  Running setup.py install for GDAL ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_spRXy/GDAL/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-NxpUaO-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying gdal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    ...
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extensions
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include -c extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extensions/gdal_wrap.o -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/gdal
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3177:27: fatal error: cpl_vsi_error.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_spRXy/GDAL/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-NxpUaO-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_spRXy/GDAL/
```

I've already tried `sudo apt-get install build-essential`, but stil the same error occurs.

Comment: This might be of some help to others - https://gist.github.com/cspanring/5680334

Comment: I am having the exact same issue

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer I found that worked:

"you might have to change the gdal version to the version installed on your host. So I had to do this since I have gdal==1.11.2 on my host:"

```
pip install gdal==1.11.2 --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal/"
```

Where the 1.11.2 should be updated to your gdal_version, which can be found in the line `# define GDAL_RELEASE_NAME` of the `/usr/include/gdal/gdal_version.h` file (at least on my system running Kubuntu).

Link to original [github page](https://gist.github.com/cspanring/5680334) with this answer from Basaks, mentioned in the comment above by Craicerjack.